# Apple pricing on screen repairs for Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware

I've cracked my new MacBook screen. A single staple that was lodged between hinges (not dropped damage). The screen is cracked and it wont display anything comprehensible. I've scoured the Internet looking for pricing ranges, from Apple Support to DIY screen replacement, no luck at all.

I don't have AppleCare+. Just purchased it last month from Best Buy. Any advice would help regarding my options for me to save some money.

Specs: 13 inch, I5, 120GB storage, no touch bar. Priced around $1200.

[image]

Comment: What year MBP?  Retina?  Non-Retina?  What specifically are you looking for here?

Comment: It doesn’t matter @Allan the per part cost is far higher than the tiered costs. Those are flat rate repairs and the OP just needs 10 minutes on the phone once they’re connected to a someone that can write up the repair.

Comment: @bmike - I was looking at this from a DIY or 3rd party perspective.  But, being that it's "new from Best Buy" it might be a moot issue at this point in time.

Comment: If the op can’t find tiered pricing on the internet, I figure they won’t be able to source a third party service and should stick with easy and get their new warranty restored. I could be wrong, though. (Also, no worries John - it stinks you’re dealing with loss - 1200 is a lot of money and to potentially find you need to spend hundreds more excuses a less than thorough research before asking for help)

Comment: Macbook PRO, Retina display.

Comment: I have research from calculating an exact cost of shipping a part from china and doing the repair myself  that seemed sketchy to contacting my credit card company about purchase protection policy. Asking fellow Consumers is my last option

Comment: Good luck. If you don’t need someone to stand behind the parts and services, DIY is a good learning experience. Also, if someone spills water on their laptop, they are looking at a tier 4 repair so see if you can buy their parts cheap.

Comment: It may not seem like it, but it helped out alot, thank you for providing a past experience with this sorta repair with apple and their price repair, which is in my budget.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple price depends how the repair is done. If you pay part by part or if you get tiered pricing.

Call or engage Apple support and they can quote you the pricing estimates for sure no matter where you are in the world. The last time I checked, tier 2 covered the display assembly and all parts and testing needed to return it to full warranty status.

You could even then get AppleCare and possible AppleCare+ once you’ve paid for the repairs.

Check your insurance to see if they will cover some of the costs - most have a higher deductable than the cost of a new Mac, but it’s worth checking.

Last time I sent in two damaged screens, the tier 2 costs in the us was about $750 for a 15 inch and $495 for smaller sized MacBook and Pro. This included all parts, labor, shipping and testing and they send a box to you so I didn’t need to deliver it or pick it up at any center.

Comment: I have contacted them and they cannot give a estimate due to the limitation of information about repair pricing on their official website. (what they told me) "I can only provide information that is provided by our website"

Comment: Ive called a third party repair service and the total charge is 968.43, which gives me no point on reparing but just buy a new one.

Comment: Don’t ask for pricing, set up a repair and get a real quote for your serial number. 1-800-APL-CARE @JohnRichie  it’s just a quote since if the damage is more than you describe, they will call you back and explain. If the damage is less than quoted, they charge you less. Third party are never able to compete with tiered pricing since Apple volume and sourcing of original parts is more cost effective than third party warehousing of new parts. Maybe in 8 years, you reconsider an aftermarket repair when used parts are cheap.